# Ansible sudo password Missing

Tags: ssh, ansible, ssh-keys

Using latest Ansible 2.9.12 on Ubuntu 18.04

Have followed the steps to **setup password less ssh,** I have the same same user on both server and node machine.

```
a@A:~> ssh-keygen -t rsa
a@A:~> ssh b@B mkdir -p .ssh
b@B's password: 
a@A:~> cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh b@B 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
b@B's password: 
a@A:~> ssh b@B  <- this works
```

`$ ansible -m ping all` <- this works

Try executing a basic ansible command:

```
  $ ansible -b all -m apt -a "name=apache2 state=latest"
      192.168.37.129 | FAILED! => {
        "msg": "Missing sudo password"
    $ ansible -b all -m apt -a "name=apache2 state=latest" -kk
    SSH password:
    192.168.37.129 | FAILED! => {
        **"msg": "Missing sudo password"
```

Anything I am missing here? Should I create a new/different user in node machine?

Comment: You seem to be confusing `ssh` and `sudo`. You have perhaps configure `ssh` to work without a password, but nowhere in your question do you show how you have configured sudo` to work without a password.

Answer (score 0):

Implemented these steps on both the server and node machine

```
$ sudo visudo #added these 2 lines
root        ALL=(ALL)        ALL
<user>  ALL=(ALL)        NOPASSWD:ALL

$ sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
PermitRootLogin yes
PasswordAuthentication yes

$ sudo service sshd restart
```

That error went away

Comment: yes, you have added the user to have password less sudo by editing the suoders file. 
Also ` PermitRootLogin` enabling this is not a good idea

Comment: @error404 - `PermitRootLogin yes` was the instruction I found on net https://www.ktexperts.com/how-to-establish-passwordless-ssh-connection-between-ansible-server-and-hosts/ . I will try without it and see if it works. Sometimes  just need to get it going

Comment: https://www.configserverfirewall.com/debian-linux/enable-debian-root-ssh-login/  what you need is a user through which you can ssh to the remote server. the user should have password less sudo enabled - this can be done in the suoders file

Comment: @error404 The link you provided also says `PermitRootLogin yes`

Comment: I have provided the link to understand the impact of modifying `PermitRootLogin yes` and not to do it.